# Notifications on the tab of browser

Tags: feature-request

The notifications that the user receive are inside the page and when they move to another page they couldn't see. Sometimes the user tend to forget to see SO if their questions are answered. So is there any update on the site where the notifications can be shown at the tab level so that it will be easy to view wherever we are inside the browser.

Comment: I hate sites that do that, so i vote no.

Comment: You must not get hundreds of notifications per-day like I do. The number at the top of this page is 152 right now, after being away from the site for a night's sleep. I mostly ignore it. I certainly wouldn't want it to interfere any *more* with my ability to get work done.

Answer (score 2):

SO is all about choice for the people. We're trying to attract experts here, and these experts have plenty of things to do and are plenty busy without playing free tech support for others.

As a result, SO is on a strictly voluntary engagement basis. Many people will close the tab and never come back after asking the question. People who keep the tab open are also likely to revisit.

Notifications are issued for many things, among them:

- When one of your posts gets edited
- When you get @mentioned in a comment
- When your question gets answered
- When one of your posts gets migrated

neither of which are time critical. If the OP comes back at all, why does it matter if they get notified *right this instant* instead of coming back on their own terms?

Also as a personal note, I hate sites who use browser features to grab my attention against my will, and SO is pleasantly absent to that at the moment, so lets keep it that way.

Comment: *"SO is all about choice for the people."* You sound like a politician running for office. I totally agree with this answer, though. If we *did* have a feature like this, it should be opt-in. Someone has probably already written something that does this; check http://stackapps.com.

Comment: @CodyGray Thats unintentional. I just heard several community managers state this over the time I've been here and was entirely too lazy to dig up quotes. :)